# Trying to convert AAC files to WAV using iTunes

Tags: audio, itunes

Trying to convert AAC files to WAV using iTunes, but I see no button for "convert using" in "edit preferences".

Am I looking in the wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

iTunes will only offer to Convert any file not in the currently chosen file type in Prefs > General > Import Settings...

<sup>Menu offset for legibility</sup>

[image]

Whatever is set here will be the only available choice when you go to File menu > Convert >

[image]

...so the trick is to change your Import Settings to the output type you require.

The prefs are the same for Mac & Windows, only the appearance is different.